# Windows and system processes

Tags: windows, process, taskmanager

Note: I've asked this question in a similiar format on superuser but it seems like it may fit here on SO better.
It definitely also is about programming as it concerns parts of the Win32 API, Windows in general and process management.

So there are these processes that can't be terminated with `taskkill` - system processes in general. But there also is, for example my Anti Virus program that makes itself "unterminateable".

- How can I access and mainly terminate system processes under windows? (kill.exe by Microsoft doesn't work)
- How do processes like anti-virus programs protect themselves? How can you turn them off again, then?

Comment: I think no one is going to answer this question. :) Maybe a hacker will... Oh, I mean the antivirus part...

Comment: For me this seems like a very important thing to know for every programmer having to do with the Windows APIs - why should only hackers (be able to) answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need API hooking to guard your process against termination. API hooking is not easy, as it requires either system-wide dll injection and memory editing or a device driver. Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) to get an idea.

Luckily, there are existing libraries out there, like [this](http://www.madshi.net/) one, which I think is shareware now unfortunately. I also found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/LibMinHook.aspx), and you can probably find more freeware stuff on google.

To answer your first question, terminating system processes is fairly easy. In C# using the [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method you can terminate system processes and cause a blue screen **if doing it from a windows system service**, at least on Windows 7 (I learned this the hard way...). Doing it using the [TerminateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from outside a service will only work if you enable certain permissions: http://www.codase.com/search/call?name=AdjustTokenPrivileges - if I'm not mistaken you need to enable SE_DEBUG_NAME.

To turn off your antivirus, well, they usually have a menu for that :). To forcefully terminate them, you'll have to use a termination method that they don't hook. [This page](http://www.diamondcs.com.au/advancedseries/processkilltechniques.php) describes a lot.

Here's a sample that can terminate the processes you want, supposing the used API functions aren't hooked. **DO NOT RUN THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING AS IT CAN CAUSE A BLUE SCREEN!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int EnablePrivilege(const char * lpPrivilegeName, BOOL bEnable)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES Privileges;
    ZeroMemory(&Privileges, sizeof(Privileges));

    HANDLE hToken;
    BOOL bResult;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        return 1;
    Privileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    Privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = (bEnable) ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpPrivilegeName,
                               &Privileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {


        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return 2;
    }
    bResult = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &Privileges, sizeof(Privileges), NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return bResult;
}

int main()
{
    cout << EnablePrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);

    HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 500); // replace 500 with the PID of the process you want to terminate - can be taken from taskmanager.

    TerminateProcess(procHandle, 0);

    CloseHandle(procHandle);
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the TerminateProcess function you've mentioned: You again need the rights to kill it (this it what it says on msdn).

Comment: Thank you, I would have had a hard time figuring it out without your help. Someone upvote this please, I can't yet.

Answer (score 0):

If terminating a process the "normal" way doesn't work, then more extreme measures are required. You can try elevating your security level, but that may not work.

Here are two rather brute force methods you can try, both requiring you to be able to successfully inject into the target application (2% failure rate on NT 4, 5% failure rate on XP, higher failure rate on Vista, Windows 7, etc).

You could try injecting a DLL into the application using CreateRemoteThread() and in the DLLMain for the injected DLL do one of the following:

- Call ExitProcess(exitCode);
- Register an exception handler, then cause an exception which you will catch with your exception handler. In your exception handler cause another exception (and/or stackoverflow). Exception during exception handling will cause instant program death.

```
void KillApp()
{
    int *p;

    p = NULL;

    __try
    {
            *b = 0;
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        killApp();
    }
}
```

[Plenty of articles on injecting using CreateRemoteThread](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx)